# Finding repeated words in a PDF

Tags: pdf, text

I wrote a 200 pages PDF and someone pointed out to me that there are some repeated words that I should eliminate.

For example, sometimes there are phrases like

`The the book is orange`

or

`the book is is orange`.

Is there a way to find such repeated words without reading all the 200 pages? Obviously I don't know what are the repeated words, otherwise, I would have just used CMD+F.

Thanks

Comment: What tool did you use to create the PDF? Are you able to copy and paste the text from the PDF into TextEdit or another editor?

Comment: @GrahamMiln It is a PDF created in LateX. I used TeXShop. Yes, I can copy to text to another editor.

Comment: You could use a [regular expression to find duplicate words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-duplicate-words).

Comment: @GrahamMiln Thanks. I am not an expert in handling regular expressions. How can I use it in the terminal?

Comment: Consider [asking a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about using regular expressions on macOS, or editing this question and title – assuming you want to head down the `regexp` approach. This will attract more focused attention and answers.